# How to tell if Newtons-Method Fails

Tags: python, algorithm, newtons-method, convex-optimization

I am creating a basic Newton-method algorithm for an unconstrained optimization problem, and my results from the algorithm are not what I expected. It is a simple objective function so it is clear that the algorithm should converge on (1,1). This is confirmed by a gradient descent algorithm I created previously, here:

```
def grad_descent(x, t, count, magnitude):
    xvalues.append(x)
    gradvalues.append(np.array([dfx1(x), dfx2(x)]))
    fvalues.append(f(x))   
    temp=x-t*dfx(x)
    x = temp
    magnitude = mag(dfx(x))    
    count+=1

    return xvalues, gradvalues, fvalues, count
```

My attempt at creating an algorithm for Newtons-Method is here:

```
def newton(x, t, count, magnitude):
  xvalues=[]
  gradvalues=[]
  fvalues=[]
  temp=x-f(x)/dfx(x)

  while count < 10:
    xvalues.append(x)
    gradvalues.append(dfx(x))
    fvalues.append(f(x))  

    temp=x-t*f(x)/dfx(x)
    x = temp
    magnitude = mag(dfx(x))    
    count+=1
    if count > 100:
      break
  return xvalues, gradvalues, fvalues, count
```

Here is the objective function and gradient function:

```
f = lambda x: 100*np.square(x[1]-np.square(x[0])) + np.square((1-x[0]))
dfx = lambda x: np.array([-400*x[0]*x[1]+400*np.power(x[0],3)+2*x[0]-2, 200*(x[1]-np.square(x[0]))])
```

Here are the initial conditions. Note that alpha and beta are not used in the newton method.

```
x0, t0, alpha, beta, count = np.array([-1.1, 1.1]), 1, .15, .7, 1
magnitude = mag(np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)]))
```

To call the function:

```
xvalues, gradvalues, fvalues, iterations = newton(x0, t0, count, magnitude)
```

This produce very strange results. Here are the first 10 iterations of the xvalues, gradient values, and function solution for its respective x input:

```
[array([-1.1,  1.1]), array([-0.99315589,  1.35545455]), array([-1.11651296,  1.11709035]), array([-1.01732476,  1.35478987]), array([-1.13070578,  1.13125051]), array([-1.03603697,  1.35903467]), array([-1.14368874,  1.14364506]), array([-1.05188162,  1.36561528]), array([-1.15600558,  1.15480705]), array([-1.06599492,  1.37360245])]
[array([-52.6, -22. ]), array([142.64160215,  73.81918332]), array([-62.07323963, -25.90216846]), array([126.11789251,  63.96803995]), array([-70.85773749, -29.44900758]), array([114.31050737,  57.13241151]), array([-79.48668009, -32.87577304]), array([104.93863096,  51.83206539]), array([-88.25737032, -36.308371  ]), array([97.03403558, 47.45145765])]
[5.620000000000003, 17.59584998020613, 6.156932949106968, 14.29937453260906, 6.7080172227439725, 12.305727666787176, 7.297442528545537, 10.926625703722639, 7.944104584786208, 9.89743708419569]
```

Here is the final output:

```
final_value = print('Final set of x values: ', xvalues[-1])
final_grad = print('Final gradient values: ', gradvalues[-1])
final_f = print('Final value of the object function with optimized inputs: ', fvalues[-1])
final_grad_mag = print('Final magnitude of the gradient with optimized inputs: ', mag(np.array([dfx1(xvalues[-1]), dfx2(xvalues[-1])])))
total_iterations = print('Total iterations: ', iterations)
```

a 3d plot is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9luhb.png)
code:

```
x = np.array([i[0] for i in xvalues])
y = np.array([i[1] for i in xvalues])
z = np.array(fvalues)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, label='Newton Method')
ax.legend()
```

Is the reasoning for this because the initial guess is so close to the optimal point, or is there some error in my algorithm that I am not catching? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. It looks like the solution may even be oscillating, but it is difficult to tell

Comment: I think we need to see the functions `f(x)` and `dfx(x)`. Also, what is the purpose (and value) of `t` in your calculations? In short, this question needs a [mcve].

Comment: Just added in f(x) and df(x). t is set to 1 for this specific algorithm, so it has no purpose.

Comment: I suspect that it's only a line or two, but could you please finish this with a main program that produces the output you show?

Comment: Just added in the function call, initial conditions, and output (anonymously on accident...) Apologies in advance for not formatting the question properly. I am new to stackoverflow and still trying to learn the ropes

Comment: Is the function and Hessian correct? To me it seems the minimum for the given function is at (1,1) not (-1,1).

Comment: You are correct that it is meant to converge at (1, 1). I've fixed that mistake in the original question. This is confirmed by the gradient descent algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what was going on with this. It was all about what data structures Python was storing my variables as. As such, I set all my values to 'float32' and initialized the variables being iterated. Working code is here:

## Note: a lambda function is an anonymous function useful for single-line expressions

```
f = lambda x: 100*np.square(x[1]-np.square(x[0])) + np.square((1-x[0]))
dfx = lambda x: np.array([-400*x[0]*x[1]+400*np.power(x[0],3)+2*x[0]-2, 200*(x[1]-np.square(x[0]))], dtype='float32')
dfx11 = lambda x: -400*(x[1])+1200*np.square(x[0])+2
dfx12 = lambda x: -400*x[0]
dfx21 = lambda x: -400*x[0]
dfx22 = lambda x: 200
hessian = lambda x: np.array([[dfx11(x), dfx12(x)], [dfx21(x), dfx22(x)]], dtype='float32')
inv_hessian = lambda x: inv(hessian(x))
mag = lambda x: math.sqrt(sum(i**2 for i in x))

def newton(x, t, count, magnitude):
  xvalues=[]
  gradvalues=[]
  fvalues=[]
  temp = np.zeros((2,1))

  while magnitude > .000005:
    xvalues.append(x)
    gradvalues.append(dfx(x))
    fvalues.append(f(x))      

    deltaX = np.array(np.dot(-inv_hessian(x), dfx(x)))
    temp = np.array(x+t*deltaX)
    x = temp
    magnitude = mag(deltaX)    
    count+=1
  return xvalues, gradvalues, fvalues, count

x0, t0, alpha, beta, count = np.array([[-1.1], [1.1]]), 1, .15, .7, 1
xvalues, gradvalues, fvalues, iterations = newton(x0, t0, count, magnitude)

final_value = print('Final set of x values: ', xvalues[-1])
final_grad = print('Final gradient values: ', gradvalues[-1])
final_f = print('Final value of the object function with optimized inputs: ', fvalues[-1])
final_grad_mag = print('Final magnitude of the gradient with optimized inputs: ', mag(np.array([dfx1(xvalues[-1]), dfx2(xvalues[-1])])))
total_iterations = print('Total iterations: ', iterations
print(xvalues)
```

Output:

```
Final set of x values:  [[0.99999995]
 [0.99999987]]
Final gradient values:  [[ 9.1299416e-06]
 [-4.6193604e-06]]
Final value of the object function with optimized inputs:  [5.63044182e-14]
Final magnitude of the gradient with optimized inputs:  1.02320249276675e-05
Total iterations:  9
[array([[-1.1],
       [ 1.1]]), array([[-1.00869558],
       [ 1.00913081]]), array([[-0.25557778],
       [-0.50186648]]), array([[-0.24460602],
       [ 0.05971173]]), array([[ 0.97073805],
       [-0.53472879]]), array([[0.97083687],
       [0.94252417]]), array([[0.99999957],
       [0.99914868]]), array([[0.99999995],
       [0.99999987]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found part of the problem. I was using the incorrect Newton's algorithm. While before I was using:
x<sub>{k+1}</sub> = x<sub>{k}</sub>-<sup>f(x)</sup>⁄<sub>∇f(x)</sub>

The correct update is:
x<sub>{k+1}</sub> = x<sub>{k}</sub> - [f''(x<sub>{k}</sub>)]<sup>-1</sup>f'(x<sub>{k}</sub>)

When I changed this, the result still diverges, but it is slightly better. The new function is here:

```
f = lambda x: 100*np.square(x[1]-np.square(x[0])) + np.square((1-x[0]))
dfx1 = lambda x: -400*x[0]*x[1]+400*np.power(x[0],3)+2*x[0]-2
dfx2 = lambda x: 200*(x[1]-np.square(x[0]))
dfx = lambda x: np.array([-400*x[0]*x[1]+400*np.power(x[0],3)+2*x[0]-2, 200*(x[1]-np.square(x[0]))])
dfx11 = lambda x: -400*(x[1])+1200*np.square(x[0])+2
dfx12 = lambda x: -400*x[0]
dfx21 = lambda x: -400*x[0]
dfx22 = lambda x: 200
hessian = lambda x: np.array(([dfx11(x0), dfx12(x0)], [dfx21(x0), dfx22(x0)]))
inv_hessian = lambda x: inv(np.array(([dfx11(x0), dfx12(x0)], [dfx21(x0), dfx22(x0)])))  

def newton(x, t, count, magnitude):
  xvalues=[]
  gradvalues=[]
  fvalues=[]
  temp = x-(inv_hessian(x).dot(dfx(x)))

  while count < 25:
    xvalues.append(x)
    gradvalues.append(dfx(x))
    fvalues.append(f(x))  

    temp = x-(inv_hessian(x).dot(dfx(x)))
    x = temp
    magnitude = mag(dfx(x))    
    count+=1
    if count > 100:
      break
  return xvalues, gradvalues, fvalues, count
```

The nearest the solution gets to converging is after the first step, where it goes to (-1.05, 1.1). However, it still diverges. I'm never worked with the Newton-method so I am unsure if this is as accurate as the algorithm is meant to get or not.

[image]

Comment: The one thing that's right about this is that the root of the derivative is either a maximum or a minimum of the function. The thing that's still unclear is whether the function, its derivative, and its second derivative are actually valid and related.

Comment: What do you mean by 'valid and related'?

Comment: "Related" means that `dfx` is actually the derivative of `f`, and `f''` is actually the derivative of `dfx`. "Valid" means smooth and continuous, and `f''` doesn't have a zero near `x`. If `f''` does have a zero near `x`, then there's a divide-by-zero problem with the algorithm.

Comment: I am certain that the derivatives are correct. As far as the validity goes, I am unsure how to check for zeroes for f''. And what constraints qualify as 'near' x? <.01 difference?

Comment: I think the best approach is to check f" before doing the division. If the value is less than epsilon (for example 1e-12), then throw an exception.

Comment: Neat properties of floating point arithmetic: dividing by near-0 quantities is only a problem if they're near 0 because of some process that causes a loss of precision. You would still need to check that it's not **exactly** 0, but there isn't any reason to choose 1e-1 vs 1e-200 for a near-0 division check at runtime.

Comment: The reason you can get loss of precision from that is if the process that produced the near-0 quantity had a loss of precision itself. Then division amplifies the problem. A classic example is subtracting two numbers that are large relative to their difference.

Comment: I understand, but f'' is not simply one number in this case. f'' is the 2x2 Hessian matrix. How would I check that a matrix is not close to zero? Also, with the updated algorithm, f'' is not being divided so I do not think that this should be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I am now certain that there is something wrong with the python code. I decided to implement the algorithm in Matlab and it seems to work fine. Here is that code:

```
clear; clc;
x=[-1.1, 1.1]';
t=1;
count=1;

xvalues=[];

temp = x - inv([(-400*x(2)+1200*x(1)^2+2), -400*x(1); -400*x(1), 200]);
disp(x-inv([(-400*x(2)+1200*x(1)^2+2), -400*x(1); -400*x(1), 200])*[-400*x(1)*x(2)+400*x(1)^3+2*x(1)-2; 200*(x(2)-x(1)^2)])

while count<10
    xvalues(count,:)= x;
    temp = x - inv([(-400*x(2)+1200*x(1)^2+2), -400*x(1); -400*x(1), 200]) * [-400*x(1)*x(2)+400*x(1)^3+2*x(1)-2; 200*(x(2)-x(1)^2)];    
    x = temp;
    count = count+1;
end

disp(xvalues)
```

Output:

```
-1.1000    1.1000
   -1.0087    1.0091
   -0.2556   -0.5018
   -0.2446    0.0597
    0.9707   -0.5348
    0.9708    0.9425
    1.0000    0.9991
    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000
```