# Graphing Newtons method in python

Tags: python, newtons-method

In the following code I have implemented Newtons method in Python.

```
import math
def Newton(f, dfdx, x, eps):
    f_value = f(x)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            x = x - float(f_value)/dfdx(x)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Error! - derivative zero for x = ", x)
            sys.exit(1)     # Abort with error
        f_value = f(x)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
    return x, iteration_counter
def f(x):
    return (math.cos(x)-math.sin(x))
def dfdx(x):
    return (-math.sin(x)-math.cos(x))
solution, no_iterations = Newton(f, dfdx, x=1, eps=1.0e-14)
if no_iterations > 0:    # Solution found
    print ("Number of function calls: %d" % (1 + 2*no_iterations))
    print ("A solution is: %f" % (solution))
else:
    print ("Solution not found!")
```

**However now I am looking to plot the convergence diagram on that same interval. This would be the absolute error as a function of the number of iterations.**

I attempted to make an iterable that each time yields a 2-tuple with the absolute error, and the iteration. Here is my code below, with the error I am getting from it included also,

```
import math
def Newton(f, dfdx, x, eps):
    f_value = f(x)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            x = x - float(f_value)/dfdx(x)
            yield interation_counter, abs(f(x))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Error! - derivative zero for x = ", x)
            sys.exit(1)     # Abort with error
        f_value = f(x)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
def f(x):
    (math.cos(x)-math.sin(x))
def dfdx(x):
    (-math.sin(x)-math.cos(x))
```

With this I tried to put the result into an array so I could graph my results

```
import numpy as np
np.array(list(Newton(f,dfdx, 1,10e-4)))
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-9378f4e2dbe3> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 np.array(list(Newton(f,dfdx, 1,10e-4)))

<ipython-input-19-40b67c2c3121> in Newton(f, dfdx, x, eps)
      4     f_value = f(x)
      5     iteration_counter = 0
----> 6     while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
      7         try:
      8             x = x - float(f_value)/dfdx(x)

TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType'
```

Comment: You forget to *return* anything in your functions ...

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @usr2564301 once that is fixed should I get the right output? my array output is giving me a 2x2

Comment: It will fix the error you got. Whether or not your algorithm is correct, I don't know.

Comment: okay well thanks for your help!

Comment: if you want another implementation to check against,`scipy` provides this in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html

Comment: this doesn't fix my problem but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest storing each value x and corresponding output f for each iteration in two respective arrays, and then returning each array. If your function is correct (you should know if it converges), then this should be easy to do. From there, just plot the array.

I did this a couple months ago. You can see how I worked through it here: 
[How to tell if Newtons-Method Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266049/how-to-tell-if-newtons-method-fails)

So A couple things to note here.

1) I did not check to make sure that your function is converging correctly or not.

2) Newtons method commonly has a very large step size and you usually won't get any pretty visualizations for its convergences. It's not uncommon for there to be <10 iterations, and they usually don't follow a smooth path to the convergence point either (once again, large step size). Notice that for the code I implemented, there were only 3 iterations. But that could just be because your function is wrong. Frankly, I'm not sure

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Newton(f, dfdx, x, eps):
    xstore=[]
    fstore=[]
    f_value = f(x)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            x = x - float(f_value)/dfdx(x)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ("Error! - derivative zero for x = ", x)
            sys.exit(1)     # Abort with error
        f_value = f(x)
        xstore.append(x)
        fstore.append(f_value)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1

    return x, iteration_counter,xstore,fstore

def f(x):
    return (math.cos(x)-math.sin(x))
def dfdx(x):
    return (-math.sin(x)-math.cos(x))

solution, no_iterations,xvalues,fvalues = Newton(f, dfdx, x=1, eps=1.0e-14)

if no_iterations > 0:    # Solution found
    print ("Number of function calls: %d" % (1 + 2*no_iterations))
    print ("A solution is: %f" % (solution))
else:
    print ("Solution not found!")

x = np.array([i for i in xvalues])
f = np.array(fvalues)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,f,label='Newton')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: could you show me how this is done with my code? I can accept the answer then

Comment: thanks for your edit. Is this a convergence plot that shows the absolute error as a function of the number of iterations? right now my code only needs 7 iterations to find my solution

Comment: I believe this just shows the answer, not the absolute error as a function of the number of iterations

Comment: No, this is only plotting the values your Newtons method iterates over (e.g. x_1, x_2, x_3, etc. w/ the corresponding objective function output for a given x) Also, your code only iterates 3 times. I do not know why you defined the number of function calls as `1 + 2*no_iterations`. I'm not following what you mean when you say 'absolute error as a function of the number of iterations.' Regardless, you should get the gist of how it's possible to visualize your output for whatever you are trying to output

Comment: how would I fix the number of iterations then?

Comment: i guess just using no_iterations would fix this

Comment: I tried with the implementation in `scipy` and I get the same answer after three evaluations of `f`, so the OP's code seems to be right

Comment: @Sam Mason so its 3 iterations? I had the output statement wrong

Comment: @fr14 I suppose it depends on your definition of what an "iteration" is, i.e. whether you want to count invocations of `f` or something else.  I also left the error tolerance as default in scipy, if you want to do more in depth testing that's up to you